# References to the macro environment

Tags: cross-referencing, documentation, dtx

Suppose I have the following in my dtx file (using `ltxdoc`):

```
%\begin{macro}{\mymacro}
%    \label{macro:mymacro}
%    Example text
%    \begin{macrocode}
\newcommand{\mymacro}[0]{An example macro}
%    \end{macrocode}
%\end{macro}
%
% ... blah blah \ref{macro:mymacro} ...
```

When I use `\ref{macro:mymacro}`, the result is empty. How can I make references to macros?

I'm using [`demopkg.dtx`](http://www.texdev.net/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/demopkg.dtx) as a MWE

Comment: They are usually not numbered, right? Maybe try `\nameref` or something similar from `hyperref` or `cleverref`.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes, they are not numbered (that explains why this doesn't work, thanks). Neither `\nameref` or `cleveref` seem to help though...

Comment: Exactly, what would you want the result of `\ref{macro:mymacro}` to look like?  For instance, should it typeset a reference to the line number?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti ideally it would be the name of the macro defined (with a link, when using `hyperref`) --- a page reference can be made with `\pageref`.

Comment: No, that was incorrect. `\pageref` would refer to the first section, subsection, ... or other labelable element before the macro.